# how to get tamil keyboard in emulator 4.1 by using typeface

Tags: android

```
   package com.example.tamil;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.graphics.Typeface;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.TextView;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      TextView txt;
      EditText ed,ed1;
      Button bt;
      Typeface fontTamil,ft;
      String str;
      @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



      ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        ft=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Tikkana.ttf");
       ed1.setTypeface(ft);         

       txt.setTypeface(ft);






         fontTamil = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Bamini.ttf");
         ed.setTypeface(fontTamil);


        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                txt.setText(ed1.getText());

            }
        });


          }




  @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       return true;
      }
     }
```

i am new face to android. i need to know about i entered below.

how to get tamil keyboard using typeface. in my coding tamil fonts are coming but but keyboard in english only. i need to change keyboard in tamil if i pressed edit text . 
this coding has no errors. but it not shows tamil keyboard.please say whether i have to add which  coding..

Comment: reply please.how to get tamil and telugu keypad when i click the edit text.